# 'let block' is only available in Mozilla JavaScript extensions (use moz option)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mozilla

I am trying the simple code below, but it is throwing the following error

> 'let block' is only available in Mozilla JavaScript extensions (use moz option)

```
let (a=20,b,c) {
  console.log(a,b,c);
}
```

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do. What do you think that code is meant to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[let block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_blocks) is non-standardized and specific to Gecko (it has been also [deprecated and removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1167029)).

JSHint requires to enable Gecko-only features with [`moz` option](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#moz).

The standard way to do this is

```
{
  let a=20,b,c;
  console.log(a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: What's the use of the curly braces here? JS doesn't have block scope right?

Comment: @evolutionxbox ES6 does. `let a = 1; { let a = 2 }` is equal to `var a = 1; (function () { var a = 2 })()` in ES5.

Comment: Only for let and const? Or for vars too?

Comment: @evolutionxbox let and const are block-scoped and non-hoisted. var keeps legacy variable behaviour. Check how Babel and Typescript transpile the code, this gives a good perspective.

Comment: The function-level scope of `var` was recognized to be confusing and limiting; block-level scope is more logical and flexible.  But ECMA didn't want to break backward compatibility.  So `var` still works the same way, but they added a new keyword `let` to do block-scope variables.  They added `const` at the same time, and gave it `let`-style behavior because, as noted, it's regarded as better.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is not ECMAScript-6.  The standard use of `let` would look like this:

```
{
  let a=20, b, c;
  console.log(a,b,c);
}
```

So whatever that syntax is, it's apparently a Mozilla extension available only when writing Mozilla-specific code.